# Reading mixed input (string/float) in same line, and storing it in arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to write a program to read a file with temperatures from various cities, for each day of the week, and in the end find the lowest and highest temperature, and output it along the day of the week in which it was measured and the city in which it was measured.
The file is formatted as such:

M
New York -5.3
Dallas 8.5
Fargo -1.3
T
New York -3.3
Dallas 5.2
Fargo -3.6
W
...

The problem I'm having is taking input and storing it in an array, because of the lines with only the name of the week. Also, I don't think I can chain the >> operators because some lines have the city New York in it, which has a white space in between. I've been wresting with this problem for days now, and I never got further than nowhere.
This is a beginner course, so keep that in mind with help :) I'll post what little code I managed to scramble, which is not much, and it doesn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string line;
    ifstream infile("temps.txt");
    float numbers[30] = { 0.0 };
    int count = 1;
    istringstream iss(line);
    string city;
    float n;


    while (getline(infile, line))
    {
        if (count % 4 == 0)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            iss >> city >> n;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << numbers[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: So your file has always the format shown above? Always a weekday followed by "New York", "Dallas", and "Fargo"? Can there be other cities? Can the number of cities variate? Should your program be able to deal with files of another format?

Comment: And would it be ok for you to work with structs and vectors/arrays of structs or should it be kept as simple as possible?

Comment: And another question: Why did you pick a size of 30 elements in `float numbers[30]`? Are there always 30 weekdays with 3 Cities every time or are there only 30 temperatures, so 10 weekdays? Or does the file contain only the information of one week?

Comment: The file always has this format, and its for only one week. So there won't be more M's or W's. I do know how to use structs and vectors, but for the final exam, we won't be able to use vectors or structs. We're only allowed to use basic arrays, so if possible I'd like to know how to do it as simple as possible. I just made it a bit larger than I know I should have, just to be safe.

Comment: Thanks so much dude, really appreciate it :)

Comment: `std::getline` + parsing the read string?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have gotten a row from the file into a string, it's easy:

```
if(line.size() == 1)
{
    // you have a day in line
}
else
{
    // you have a <city + temperature>, let's parse
    // the last space in line is always the one right before the temperature. Here is it's index.
    int lastSpace = line.find_last_of(' '); 

    int temp = std::stoi(line.substr(lastSpace + 1, line.size()));
    string cityName = line.substr(0, lastSpace);
}
```

After you have gotten the temperature as an int and the city name as a string, you can store them however you want (array, map, list, whatever) to get the max temperature of the week.